how to mask continuous actions? (ml agents)
i want to mask one of my Continuous Actions based on one of my Discrete Actions. is it possible to do this? because i didn't find any code/tutorial for this.
here's a pseudo code:
if Actions.Discrete[0] == 0
  Mask_Action(ContinuousAction[0], True) # agent CAN'T use this action
else if Actions.Discrete[0] == 1
  Mask_Action(ContinuousAction[0], False) # agent CAN use this action

thank you.
